# Modulo equation

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to find:

- Prime $p$ such that $p\neq 1+7x^2$ for every $x\in \Bbb Z$
- Integer $a$ such that $1+7a^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$

I don't want the trivial answer where $p=2$ and $a=1$, as I need a way to solve it in general.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you know about quadratic residues and quadratic reciprocity?

Comment: Could you give a bit more context? What kind of material has been covered up to this point? Have you for example covered the law of quadratic reciprocity?

Comment: @DanielFischer ,i haven't study these theorems, but if you write the proof ,i may understand it. thank you

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen i haven't study these theorems, but if you write the proof ,i may understand it. thank you